# Will there be any leak in below C++ shared_ptr usage?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Is the allocated memory managed by a smart pointer guaranteed to be freed up in event of an exception, such as below?

```
#include <memory>

void test( std::shared_ptr<int> sptr )
{
    throw "exception";
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr( new int(1) );
    test( ptr );
    return 0;
}
```

I tried executing the code, putting breakpoint at `shared_ptr` destructor but I did not see it getting called.  I think the memory should be cleaned up by itself.  Am I right, or won't it be cleaned up?

Comment: Freed up *when*? Since there's no more code to run, there's nothing to free it up for.

Answer (score 6):

The language standard states that:

> If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is
>   called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to
>   `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined

So your program isn't guaranteed to clean up after itself, but most (if not all) modern operating systems will do it post-mortem.

Had you caught the exception, the `shared_ptr`'s instance would've been destroyed properly, ensuring no leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Take better example for understanding:

> ```
> #include <memory>
> #include <windows.h>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> class A
> {
> public:
>   A()
>   {
>       cout << "Constructor" << endl;
>   }
>   ~A()
>   {
>       cout << "destructor" << endl;
>   }
> };
>
> void test(std::shared_ptr<A> sptr)
> {
>   throw "exception";
> }
>
> void function()
> {
>   std::shared_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
>   test(ptr);
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>   function();
>   Sleep(5000);
> }
> ```

Before Program crash only one constructor gets called which shows it does not do destruction.
But if we do debugging in visual studio and say continue after exception then even destructor gets called.